# How can I create a type with one property from a parameter?

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to implement a type that would be as follows:

```js
type Response = {
 register: AuthPayload
}
```

However, I want the `register` part to be variable. Something like:

```js
type Response<T> = {
  T: AuthPayload
}
```

Which I could use like:

```js
type RegisterResponse = Response<"register">
// type RegisterResponse = { register: AuthPayload }
type LoginResponse = Response<"login">
// type LoginResponse = { login: AuthPayload }
```

I tried looking into mapped types and indexed types but none of these solve what I am looking for (at least to my understanding). This may be a very trivial question, if so, please direct me to the relevant documentation.

Comment: `Record<T, AuthPayload>`?

Comment: Culling from @CertainPerformance, you can use `Record<T extends string, AuthPayload>`